# Border radius is not working when include it on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make multiple select box in my project. Multiple select box is working but my design is not working i mean my css radius border is not working. In the below i give you codes:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#institute').multiselect({
      nonSelectedText: 'Select Institute',
      enableFiltering: true,
      enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
      borderRadius: '8.4rem',
      buttonWidth:'500px',
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="institute">Select:</label>
    <select id="institute" multiple class="form-control">
        <option>Select Trainning Institute</option>
        <option value="pt">Pt</option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="it">IT</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you think that `borderRadius` is a valid [configuration option](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `borderRadius` option for `bootstrap-multiselect`. Try the code below instead.

```
$('#institute').css({
    borderRadius: '8.4rem'
});
```

Comment: Would like to know why someone gave this a downvote. Idea looked good to me, so would be good to know what the issue was?

Answer (score 1):

Js is not applied to element because border radius is not there in #institute element .. Border radius is applied on button.multiselect so to change it Please add this style in js,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#institute').multiselect({
      nonSelectedText: 'Select Institute',
      enableFiltering: true,
      enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
      buttonWidth:'500px',
  });
  $('.multiselect').css('border-radius','8.5rem');
});
```

Refrence demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/jignashagpatel/csq9we25/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is the update code for you questions.
you have no options to set border-radius directly in Bootstrap-Multiselect.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="institute">Select:</label>
        <select id="institute" multiple class="form-control">
            <option>Select Trainning Institute</option>
            <option value="pt">Pt</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="it">IT</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#institute').multiselect({
              nonSelectedText: 'Select Institute',
              enableFiltering: true,
              enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
              buttonWidth:'500px',
          });
          $('.multiselect').css('border-radius','8.5rem');
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When we want to use css in a js file, use the .css function

```
$('#institute').multiselect({
              nonSelectedText: 'Select Institute',
              enableFiltering: true,
              enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
              borderRadius: '40px',
              buttonWidth:'500px',
          });
          $('.multiselect').css({'border-radius':'8.4rem'});
```